# Assets not loading in localhost for a laravel app

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an application which has developed on laravel 5.7 and it's index.php is moved to root directory. Now when i tried to make the server up using php artisan serve command.

The website was loading but assets files like css and js not loading. Entire console showing errors and when i tried to see the asset file code through http://localhost:8000/assets/js/app.min.js

It was showing Error 404

The page you are looking for does't exist.

Can any one help me i am trying to resolve from past two days

Entire app is loading only view is not proper due to non loading of asset files

Comment: Where have you kept your assets folder in the project directory structure?

Comment: How are you loading the assets from the blade?